# Horário de verão no Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, integração-contínua

Tenho uma instância do Jenkins rodando em um Windows Server 2016 e este servidor está com o hora correta.

Tenho algumas jobs configuradas para rodar com hora especifica, porém elas estão rodando um uma hora adiantada, como se tivesse com horário de verão ainda.

Nas configurações do Jenkins tenho o seguinte:

```
user.timezone:America/Sao_Paulo
```

Alguém teve o mesmo problema e conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jovens, resolvi o problema atualizando os timezones da JDK usando o TzUpdater.

Realmente o problema não está no Jenkins e sim na sua JDK.

Segue link:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html

Faça download do TzUpdater e rode no seu servidor que tem o Jenkins:

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Galera, no meu caso, a solução acima não funcionou, não consegui utilizar o TzUpdate (não sei por qual motivo, provavelmente limitação do proxy da empresa), mas consegui achar outra solução para que possa ser tentada também.

Basta atualizar o java da máquina e desinstalar as versões antigas. Quando realizei este processo consegui corrigir o problema do horário errado no meu Jenkins.

Comment: Também é possível baixar o TzUpdater fora do seu proxy, coloca-ló em algum servidor (IIS por exemplo) e indica-lo caminho no parametro -l.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling Mesmo baixando por fora e tentando passar por parâmetro na minha máquina não estava conseguindo atualizar, tentei de todas as formas porém sem sucesso

Comment: Mas qual motivo de não ter funcionado?

Comment: Ele não conseguia realizar a atualização do TZUpdate, possivelmente por que meu usuário não possuí permissão de ADM da máquina...
Já a instalação do Java era feita via Portal então foi possível atualizar.